# Handling application crashes with Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I'm using Robotium to execute automation tests on Android.
The problem is that when executing a bunch of tests, if any test causes application crash - no further tests will be executed. Only this message will appear "Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''. Check device logcat for details".

I've tried to use try\catch on runTest() but there are no exception thrown when app crashes.

```
    public void runTest() throws Throwable {
        try {
            super.runTest();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            String testCaseName = String.format("%s.%s", getClass().getName(), getName());
            solo.takeScreenshot(testCaseName);
            Logging.w(Logging.TAG.Test, String.format("Captured screenshot for failed test: %s", testCaseName));
            t.printStackTrace();
            String out = "";
            for (StackTraceElement s : t.getStackTrace()) {
                out = out + s.toString() + "\n";
            }
            fail(t.getMessage() + "\n" + out);
        }
    }
```

But there are still "Test failed to run to completion...." message and all test execution stops.

It's ok that current test fails, problem is that next tests are not executed. Does someone solved this problem? Is there a way to handle application exception right from tests?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
System.exit(0)
```

inside of code. When main application exit in such way it's process gets killed and along with that robotium tests are killed (they are living in same process).
For me the solution was to remove System.exit(0) from code of main application.

Comment: It sometimes helps to replace System.exit(0) with finish(), if the app relies on the exit.